# MS Edge and IE11 Enterprise Mode Site List

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a website that uses an ActiveX object. I know that ActiveX is not supported by MS Edge. To let my website work correctly I need to add it to the Enterprise Mode Site List and configure Edge to use this list.

My question is, does this configuration mean that Edge will stay open and show my website but behind the scene in IE11 mode or does it mean that Edge will launch a instance (new window) of IE11 and display my website in there?

I don't have Windows 10 and Edge to test it on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test your application, to get some testing platform, [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) are available VMs for exactly your need.

For your question, even if my advice stay, lab test it please...

Using the Enterprise Mode Site list

For Internet Explorer 11, Enterprise Mode is configured by enabling the Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list Group Policy. You must then specify the location (URL) of the Enterprise Mode Site List under Options.  You can configure Microsoft Edge in a similar way using the Microsoft Edge Allows you to configure Enterprise Site list Group Policy.   That Group Policy specifies the location of the Enterprise Mode Site List for Microsoft Edge. If you enable this policy but do not specify a location for the Enterprise Mode Site List, Microsoft will automatically use the IE11 Enterprise Mode Site List if one exists.

DoNotTransition : False = **This site on the Enterprise Mode Site List will transition to Internet Explorer 11 when opened in Microsoft Edge**

Read more [here](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/08/26/how-microsoft-edge-and-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-10-work-better-together-in-the-enterprise/#xvyBoducZdg5OV2E.97)

Comment: I've checked that site before posting my question. I just want to know what will Edge do in such case, open my site in a new window IE11 or stay in Edge self.

Comment: @Stacked Then why you didn't downloaded a VM to test it out ? It got VirtualBox VM or VMWare image (with a player) that you can easilly run.

Comment: @Stacked Edited my answer for your question